# Extract only MAC addresses from arp-scan -l

Tags: mac-address, arp

I want to collect only MAC addresses from `arp-scan -l`, omitting IP addresses and the devices name. How do we do it? I know that these in the middle column are all MAC addresses.

```
192.168.1.1 bc:98:89:47:20:f8   Fiberhome Telecommunication Technologies Co.,LTD
192.168.1.3 70:18:8b:5e:01:fd   Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
192.168.1.5 90:e7:c4:da:80:76   HTC Corporation
192.168.1.6 b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25   Raspberry Pi Foundation
```

I want like this

```
bc:98:89:47:20:f8
70:18:8b:5e:01:fd   
90:e7:c4:da:80:76
b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25
```

**Edit:**

arp-scan -l gives the following result

```
Interface: wlp5s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)
192.168.1.1 bc:98:89:47:20:f8   Fiberhome Telecommunication Technologies Co.,LTD
192.168.1.5 90:e7:c4:da:80:76   HTC Corporation
192.168.1.3 70:18:8b:5e:01:fd   Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
192.168.1.5 90:e7:c4:da:80:76   HTC Corporation (DUP: 2)
192.168.1.6 b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25   Raspberry Pi Foundation
192.168.1.6 b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25   Raspberry Pi Foundation (DUP: 2)
192.168.1.4 80:35:c1:4a:a5:dc   (Unknown)

9 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 3.017 seconds (84.85 hosts/sec). 7 responded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using a linux-like shell and `awk` utility is installed( it is mostly pre-installed )-

`arp-scan -l | awk '/.*:.*:.*:.*:.*:.*/{print $2}'`

Comment: but it still has some residuals
`wlp5s0,`
`arp-scan`
`bc:98:89:47:20:f8`
`70:18:8b:5e:01:fd`
`b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25`
`80:35:c1:4a:a5:dc`

`packets`
`arp-scan`

Comment: I had that query made based on the response you pasted in the question. And for the same response, my solution works fine.

Comment: Isn't the command response you pasted above is 'whole', if not, making it whole would be nicer.

Comment: I need response like the response I showed after "I need like this"

Comment: That is what the solution gives. I tested with the text - `192.168.1.1 bc:98:89:47:20:f8   Fiberhome Telecommunication Technologies Co.,LTD
192.168.1.3 70:18:8b:5e:01:fd   Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
192.168.1.5 90:e7:c4:da:80:76   HTC Corporation
192.168.1.6 b8:27:eb:b0:4d:25   Raspberry Pi Foundation`

If the above mentioned test-case is not correct, replace the result of the `arp-scan -l` in the question, first-line to last-line.

Comment: I have added the entire response in Edit section

Answer (score 0):

Learn basic Unix shell!

In particular the `cut` command can be used to extract columns from text. Set the field separator to space (probably default) and select the second field.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--plain` option of arp-scan can make things easier. It will display  plain output showing only responding hosts. The hosts' information are separated by tab, MAC address (2nd column) can be extracted easily through `cut`, as Anony-Mousse described:

`arp-scan -l --plain | cut -f 2`